# Symfony2 | Error: Invalid serialization data for datetime object

Tags: arrays, symfony, serialization, dbal

I've been seeing this error in my logs for a couple of days ago when I did a composer update of my project.

```
[2015-09-28 17:51:21] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Error: Invalid serialization data for DateTime object
```

Is it a bug Symfony2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should provide more information, if you want someone help you. But for now, I can suggest you to look at [this](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68889&thanks=6) issue posted on [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net).

Here is the solution posted there:

```
public function serialize() {
    return \serialize(array($this->myDateTimeObj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
}
```

Comment: Where i must to place that?

Comment: @phpprogrammer I don't know the structure of your project.. May be in some security classes (I usually implement \Serializable interface in my User class which implements the UserInterface), may be in vendor bundles.. There should be  some objects which are being serialized..